# Displaying content from different mongoose tables on one view

Tags: node.js, mongodb, asynchronous, express, mongoose

I'm a (relatively inexperienced) Java EE developer who is looking to learn node.js. I'm working with the express framework, mongodb, and the mongoose framework. I've been working on building a simple blog site (just for practice) with an mvc like architecture. It would have would have 4 mongodb collections: post, image, user, comment. The basic Schemas are as follows:

```
postSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    id: Number,
    dateCreated, {type: Date, default: Date.now}
    title: String,
    content: String
});
var Post = mongoose.model('Post', postSchema);

imageSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    id: Number, 
    postId: Number,
    path: String
});

var Image = mongoose.model('Image', imageSchema);

userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    id: Number, 
    username: String,
    password: String,
    email: String
});

var User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);

commentSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    id: Number,
    postId: Number,
    userId: Number, 
    dateCreated: {type: Date, default: Date.now},
    content: String
});

var Comment = mongoose.model('Comment', commentSchema);
```

I want to be able to show a post, an image, comments, and user info all on one page. My issue is that I can't quite figure out how retrieve and send all this data in an asynchronous way. This seems to be what most of the examples I have found do (not necessarily all in one file):

```
app.get('/', function(res, req) {
    Post.findOne(function(err, post) {
         if (err) return res.send(500);
         res.render('index', post);
    });
});
```

This wouldn't work for me because I would info from the image, comment, and user collections as well. Is there an asynchronous way to do this? If not is there a way to reconfigure what I have so that it could be asynchronous? (I'm trying to get a feel for asynchronous programming.)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simples way to do this as-is would be to use promises and perform simultaneous async operations:

```
Post.findOne(id).then(post => {
    let postId = post.id;
    return Promise.all([
        Comments.find({postId}),
        Images.find({postId}),
        // Not sure what query you need here
        User.find(),
        post,
    ]);
}).then(data => {
    let [comments, images, users, post] = data;
    res.render('index', {comments, images, users, post});
});
```

In your `index` template you would have an object with the four properties.

You can perform simultaneous async operations without promises, but I'll leave that for someone else to talk about. I would prefer to work with promises.

---

Mongoose will also allow you to use other schema definitions as data types as in:

```
commentSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    id: Number,
    postId: Post,
    userId: User, 
    dateCreated: {type: Date, default: Date.now},
    content: String
});
```

In this case you can use [`.populate`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html) after some queries in order to perform another query under the hood -- e.g. get the post data for a comment.

---

Since you are using MongoDB -- a NoSQL Database -- I would look into denormalizing the data and keeping it flat.  [Firebase, which stores data in a similar structure has a great article on how to store and use denormalized data](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/structuring-data.html)